# WPF ウィンドウ枠線部の色を指定したい

Tags: c#, wpf

Windows 7 上の Visual Studio 2010 Professional with MSDN で開発をしております。

WPFアプリケーションのウィンドウ枠線部の色を指定したいのですが、
ウィンドウ全体の背景色を指定する方法しかわかりませんでした。

何か良い実現方法はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 枠線部]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010という事は.NET 4.0.x系までしか使えないため、`WindowChrome`クラスによるカスタマイズすらも行えなかったと思うので、正攻法ではおそらく不可能です。

`WindowChrome`クラスの利用自体は.NET 4.0.xでも`WPF Shell Integration Library`に含まれるdllを参照すれば可能らしいですが、`WindowChrome`クラスを使ったとしてもそこまで詳細なデザインは出来なかったかと…

強引にでもやる必要があるのであれば、　
`Window`クラスの`WindowStyle`プロパティを`WindowStyle.None`に、`ResizeMode`プロパティを`ResizeMode.NoResize`に指定して非クライアント領域を完全に削除し、自分で「Windowの枠、キャプション、キャプチャ判定、システムボタン」等をエミュレーションするしかないでしょう。